# How to programatically create a Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) Workspace & add a project to it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to *programatically* create a Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) workspace, and add projects to it. How do I do this with an API?

Answer (score -2):

Every workspace must have a host project. So you would have to create the original project before trying to find a way to add more projects. From Google’s documentation :
“Every Workspace has a host project. The host project is the Google Cloud project used to create the Workspace. The name of the Workspace is set to the name of host project. This isn't configurable.”

Comment: Creating a project with an API can be done as per this link : 
Creating a project : 
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project

There does not appear to be an API for creating Cloud Monitoring workloads in GCP, you may be better off trying to create a feature request.

Comment: Thanks!  But what I am trying to do is create a Cloud Monitoring _workspace_ using an API.  I assume that the projects are already in existence.